# python pyqt5 mouseEvent and mouseLocation

Tags: python, user-interface, events, pyqt5, mouse

I'm trying to make videogame macro with pyautogui and pyqt5

this is what I want

1. Press the button and hold it. (mouse pressed)
2. Drag somewhere outside the GUI window.
3. release it. (mouse released)
4. Get the mouse location when the mouse is released

but I couldn't find a way to connect mouse event with button clicks.

```
class MyWindow(QDialog, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mouseLocation = {}
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        
        self.menuBtn.clicked.connect( lambda: self.addLocation('MenuBtn'))   # ButtonEvents
        self.traininBtn.pressed.connect( lambda: self.addLocation('TraininBtn'))
        self.difficultyBtn.pressed.connect( lambda: self.addLocation('DifficultyBtn'))
        self.lonewolfBtn.pressed.connect( lambda: self.addLocation('LonewolfBtn'))
        
    def addLocation(self, name):
        self.mouseLocation[name] = [pyautogui.position().x, pyautogui.position().y]

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e): 
        print('BUTTON RELEASED')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent ?

Comment: `print(e.globalPos())`

Comment: @alec e is not defined. how to transmit e to other?